# source % is not an editor command in vim?

Tags: vim

Error detected while processing /home/USER/.vimrc:

line   31:

E492: Not an editor command: bundle ‘vim-ruby/vim-ruby'

I need help. I switched to vim and its been hell as of now. I dont even know whats going on since morning trying to  find out what am i doing wrong.

```
  1 set number 
  2 
  3 set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
  4 filetype off                  " required
  5 
  6 " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
  7 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
  8 call vundle#begin()
  9 " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
 10 "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')
 11 
 12 " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
 13 Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
 14 
 15 " The following are examples of different formats supported.
 16 " Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
 17 " plugin on GitHub repo
 18 Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
 19 " plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
 20 " Plugin 'L9'
 21 " Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
 22 Plugin 'https://github.com/wincent/Command-T.git'
 23 " git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
 24 " The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
 25 " Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
 26 Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
 27 " Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
 28 " different version somewhere else.
 29 " Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}
 30 
 31 bundle ‘vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
 32 " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
 33 call vundle#end()            " required
 34 filetype plugin indent on    " required
 35 " To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
 36 "filetype plugin on
 37 "
 38 " Brief help
 39 " :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
 40 " :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
 41 " :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
 42 " :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
 43 "
 44 " see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
 45 " Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong command to install the vim-ruby plugin. You can refer to the project's [documentation](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/VimRubySupport) for more details. As for your `.vimrc`, the correct installation with Vundle should be like this:

```
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
call vundle#end()
```

After modifying your `.vimrc`, run the `:PluginInstall` command from within vim.

Comment: @jimmagatwech, also note that your original version appears to have a "smart (single-)quote" at the start the plugin name/path, rather than the plain single-quote at the end. Change that to also be plain, as pandadestein has.